# Display failure after waking up from standby

Tags: macbook-pro, display

for some days I am experiencing a very strange behavior when my MacBook Air (newest generation) wakes up from the standby modus.

Instead of the login view there are just many white and black lines across the screen. When I shut it down (pressing the off button for 5 secs) and start it again, everything works fine again.

Does anyone have the same experiences or know a solution to this?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: I have a similar situation on my macbook.  It doesn't show black-white, but it does not reactivate the screen.  Closing the lid, waiting, and reopening will fix it most of the time.  Have you tried re-closing the system, waiting for sleep, and reopening?  Also, I run quite a few heavy programs constantly, so i'm not sure what is doing it.  My worst (i think) is when Flash is open in a Chrome tab and playing video, but that may be 1/2 to do with vpn disconnection issues delaying something.

Comment: Nope, I haven not tried it before to put it back into sleep and open it again. Additionally, I am also running big programs actually in different spaces (matlab, Xcode, ...) and have dozens of windows open. I will dig into this and check if this causes it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are seeing something like this, I suggest you contact [Apple Support](http://www.apple.com/support/contact/) for a hardware check.

Picture from [Apple support communities.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2806499?start=0&tstart=0)

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks, yep that's exactly what I see. But it might be a software problem because of after a reboot it is away.